# wcf and the plague called Hao123

Tags: wcf, malware

I have a WCF service that uses HTTP (and a specific port, of course) to communicate over a network. Whenever this service is installed on computers with the "application" Hao123 (and also other types such as TermBlazer, Ad-Search, etc), it does not work right, because all requests made to him not even reach contracts created.

What could I do to protect my application of this type of malware? I believe be unfeasible to create a "removal tool" for each type of pest such that I can find in the user's machine. Failing to install my service is not an option.

Comment: Why does your _client_ application need a WCF service? Why do you want to support machines that aren't maintained properly? Why don't requests work anymore, does this malware install an HTTP proxy?

Comment: Basically, I can say that my WCF application is a software required for the operation of these applications. Like a server for them. These applications are desktop applications.